# Where to use all

Tags: word-order

*Must all vs all must* which is correct why?

Example sentences :

> We all must try to find a solution to the problem
>
> We must all try to find a solution to the problem

Please clarify me

Comment: They're both correct as far as I'm concerned. Should this be moved to the ELL site?

Comment: Agreed, both are correct. And add this form: **"All of us must try to find a solution,"** which is also correct.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is much difference between them.

And as Hugh correctly stated, you may even use

> All of us must try to find a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct and mean the same thing.

Sometimes changing the word order in English changes emphasis, but in this case, no. They mean the same thing.